# How to locate file in the root folder when uploaded to web c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
AlternateView av = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
LinkedResource lr = new LinkedResource("C:\\Users\\reynan\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\TrackAndTrace\\TrackAndTrace\\Images\\CNT logo.jpg",
                    MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
```

I have a minor problem when locating a file in my folders when uploaded to web. How can locate images like "../images/logo.jpg" in html to C# code.

How should i change this code

> LinkedResource lr = new
>   LinkedResource("C:\Users\reynan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\TrackAndTrace\TrackAndTrace\Images\CNT logo.jpg",
>                       MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);

Answer (score 0):

Use `Server.MapPath`

```
 LinkedResource lr = new LinkedResource(Server.MapPath(@"~\Images\CNT logo.jpg"),
                     MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
```

the root of the website is denoted by `~`, so you can set the relative path to it.